# C# How to create custom section without parent node

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config, configurationmanager, custom-sections

I have worked by below article.

http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/net-custom-configuration-section-collection-and-elements/

I can achieve if I do like what it said. But I want to remove parent node. I want xml to seems like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="jobSection"
      type="MyConfiguration.JobSection, MyConfiguration" />
  </configSections>
  <jobSection>
      <job id="1" name="Job Name A" />
      <job id="2" name="Job Name B" />
  </jobSection>
</configuration>
```

I get an error `Unrecognized element 'job'.` if xml is like above. 
How can I define a custom section by above xml ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your configuration class, you should define the `ConfigurationProperty` attribute on the collection with an empty string as name and with the `IsDefaultCollection` property set to true:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]  
public JobsCollection Jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your post is look similar with below post.Please look the post it may help you.

[Unrecognized element "Item" in config file with custom config section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113314/unrecognized-element-item-in-config-file-with-custom-config-section)